# I used these codes but return an error as an invalid string Format

Tags: vb.net

I used these codes but return an error as an invalid string Format.

can you guide me?:)

```
Dim orderRequest As BamboraOrderRequest = New BamboraOrderRequest
orderRequest.id = objCartData.GetOrderNumberWithoutInceasing()

If Session("CardPaymentTotalPrice").ToString().Contains(",") Then

    orderRequest.amount = Convert.ToInt32(Session("CardPaymentTotalPrice").ToString().Replace(",", ""))

Else

    orderRequest.amount = Convert.ToInt32(Session("CardPaymentTotalPrice").ToString())


End If
orderRequest.currency = "DKK"
```

Comment: How is this related to VBA?

Comment: It is hard to tell what is wrong without knowing what is the value of `Session("CardPaymentTotalPrice")`

Comment: Why are you getting a value from session, converting it to a `String` and then converting it to an `Integer` in the first place? If the value is supposed to be an `Integer` then put an `Integer` in and then get an `Integer` out. You can then just cast instead of convert, i.e. `orderRequest.amount = CInt(Session("CardPaymentTotalPrice"))`. Stop creating problems in the first place and then you won't need help solving them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the information you have provided, it is unclear where the error occurs and what values are given, but you could try editing the code as follows to see if that helps:

```
Dim orderRequest As BamboraOrderRequest = New BamboraOrderRequest
orderRequest.id = objCartData.GetOrderNumberWithoutInceasing()

orderRequest.amount = Convert.ToInt32(Session("CardPaymentTotalPrice").ToString().Replace(",", ""))

orderRequest.currency = "DKK"
```

The [String.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-5.0) method only replaces the character if it exists, eliminating the need for the `If` statement.
Try this and if it doesn't work please provide more details about the issue. It would also be helpful to know what value `Session("CardPaymentTotalPrice")` returns.